# How to Bend Lines on an HTML Canvas using a Mouse Hover

Tags: javascript, canvas, vector-graphics

The following code draws a grid of lines across an HTML canvas element:

Is it possible to bend/distort the lines when the mouse hovers near a line?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('grid');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ww = innerWidth; // Window Width
var wh = innerHeight; // Window Height

canvas.width = ww;
canvas.height = wh;

function drawLines() {
    for(var i = 0; i < ww; i += 30) {
        context.moveTo(i , 0);
        context.lineTo(i , wh);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < wh; i += 30) {
        context.moveTo(0, i);
        context.lineTo(ww, i);
    }

    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = "#333";
    context.stroke();
}

drawLines();
```

```css
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
```

```html
<canvas id="grid"></canvas>
```

Comment: you need [this](https://codepen.io/dissimulate/pen/KrAwx).

Answer (score 0):

You have to store all of the `x, y` grid values in an 2d array then render them appropriately.

And add some kind of physics behavior to all of the `points` 
[verlet physics](https://youtu.be/3HjO_RGIjCU) will be nice or [spring physics](https://youtu.be/JywnkK6Iuws)

pseudocode

```
        for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                points.push([
                    x,y,
                ])
                x += gap;
            }
            y += gap;
        }
```